# Spring cloud gateway as a forward proxy

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

Can we use Spring cloud gateway as a forward proxy, I tied don't it and was stuck with HTTPS traffic
The Gateway could not support 'HTTPS - CONNECT Requests' I am aware that Netty is used underneath but like to use the other capabilities of the gateway so wanted to use it as a forward proxy

Use case
Have a few internal site URLs in gateway route rules and the rest of the URL has to be a pass-thru like how a forward proxy will work. I have a sample wild card configuration to test forward proxy setting but HTTPS traffic fails to pass thru.

```
cloud:
gateway:
  routes:
  - id: wildcard_route
    uri: no://op
    predicates:
    - Path=/**
```

I need some direction on how to enable forward proxy in Spring cloud gateway